# when I Add new element dynamically to droppable area all the existing elements are not droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have my html containers as follows and it has number of levels.

```
    <div id='levels'>
    <div id="level6" class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <ul id="6" class="levelBucket">
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="level5" class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <ul id="5" class="levelBucket">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

When the page loads I fetch required elements from DB and appended to the relevant ULs using below HTML.

```
   <li class='dataWrapper' >
   <div>content..</div>
   </li>
```

When all the LI elements are in place I use following java script to make fields Draggable and Droppable.

```
function AddDraggableDropperbleFunctionality() {

var selectedClass = 'areaSelected';

$('.levelBucket li').draggable({
    revert: true,
    start: function (e, ui) {
        ui.helper.addClass(selectedClass);
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {},
    drag: function (e, ui) {}
});


  $(".levelBucket").sortable().droppable({
    over: function (e, ui) { $(this).addClass(selectedClass); },
    out: function (e, ui) { $(this).removeClass(selectedClass); },
    drop: function (e, ui) {

       //Do all the updates

    }
});

}
```

After page loads all the Draggable and Droppable functionality are working fine. There is a separate button in my page to add LI elements dynamically. When I add new element I call the above Java script method again to make newly added item draggable. But actually what happen is newly added LI is working fine with draggable and droppable and all the existing LIs are not droppable anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using following method to add 'LI' element to the levelBuckets.

```
 consultantContainer.innerHTML += consultantWrapper;
```

But after I modified the above line as below mentioned way, my problem was solved. I think the problem is using innerHTML to append elements and it affects the draggable functionality.

```
$(consultantWrapper).appendTo('#' + level);
```

Edit: Here is a more explicit example to clarify the use of [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/).

```
$('<div class="arbitraryClass">arbitraryContent</div>').appendTo('#' + arbitraryID);
```